# How can I solve this problem in seaborn boxplot of flexible type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

When I run the following code it produces an error

```
 print(sns.boxplot(x=add_cng['STUDENT_ID']))
 sns.boxplot(x="variable", y="value", data=pd.melt(st_attendance['ATTENDANCE']))
```

This is the error

> TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Can someone tell me how to resolve this error?

Comment: Are the values in `st_attendance['ATTENDANCE']` all numeric?

Comment: Yeah..
This field is numeric data type..

Comment: Can you post some of the data you are using?